# How to stop calling a method from another method in java?

Tags: java, methods, calculator

I have a calculator code and the problem is:

```
 public void valueCheck(String value,JToggleButton button) {
        if(values.size()>2) 
        {
            processValue(value);
            button.setSelected(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You cant click 3 buttons at the same time..");
        }
    }
```

There is a method valueCheck and:

```
public boolean evenOdd(JToggleButton buton)
    {
        if(values.size()==2)
        {
        System.out.println((String)values.get(0));
        System.out.println((String)values.get(1));

        String number1 = new String(values.get(0));
        String number2 = new String(values.get(1));

        if(evenNumbers.contains(number1))
        {
            if(evenNumbers.contains(number2))
            {
                processValue(number1);
                processValue(number2);
            }
            else if(oddNumbers.contains(number2))
            {
                buton.setSelected(false);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You cant click an even and an odd number at the same time..");

            }
        }
        else if(oddNumbers.contains(number1))
        {
            if(oddNumbers.contains(number2))
            {
                processValue(number1);
                processValue(number2);
            }
            else if(evenNumbers.contains(number2))
            {
                buton.setSelected(false);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You cant click an even and an odd number at the same time..");
            }
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

there is a method evenOdd.

My problem is: I dont want valueCheck method to run for evenOdd method.When evenOdd method runs valueCheck must be stopped calling.Is there a event to do this?I want to stop calling valueCheck when evenOdd is running

Here is my whole code.

```
package tr.com.bites;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.StopParseException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
public class CalculatorView_1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     JToggleButton[] buttons =  new JToggleButton[4];
    public CalculatorView_1() {
        initComponents();
        buttons[0]=jToggleButton12;
        buttons[1]=jToggleButton11;
        buttons[2]=jToggleButton10;
        buttons[3]=jToggleButton13;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton2 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton3 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton4 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton5 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton6 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton7 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton8 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton9 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton10 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton11 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton12 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton13 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton14 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jToggleButton1.setText("1");
        jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton2.setText("2");
        jToggleButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton3.setText("3");
        jToggleButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton4.setText("5");
        jToggleButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton5.setText("4");
        jToggleButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton6.setText("6");
        jToggleButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton7.setText("8");
        jToggleButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton8.setText("7");
        jToggleButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton9.setText("9");
        jToggleButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton10.setText("*");
        jToggleButton10.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton10ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton11.setText("-");
        jToggleButton11.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton11ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton12.setText("+");
        jToggleButton12.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton12ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton13.setText("/");
        jToggleButton13.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton13ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton14.setText("=");
        jToggleButton14.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton14ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton8)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton7)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton9))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton5)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton4)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton6))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton3)))
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(78, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton12)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton11)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton10))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton2)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton3))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton5)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton4)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton6))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton8)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton7)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton9))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jToggleButton13)
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton14)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(90, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("1");
       valueCheck("1",jToggleButton1);
       evenOdd(jToggleButton1);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("2");
       valueCheck("2",jToggleButton2);
       evenOdd(jToggleButton2);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("3");
       valueCheck("3",jToggleButton3);
       evenOdd(jToggleButton3);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("4");
       valueCheck("4",jToggleButton5);
       evenOdd(jToggleButton5);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("5");
       valueCheck("5",jToggleButton4);
       evenOdd(jToggleButton4);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("6");
       valueCheck("6",jToggleButton6);
       evenOdd(jToggleButton6);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("7");
       valueCheck("7",jToggleButton8);
       evenOdd(jToggleButton8);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("8");
       valueCheck("8",jToggleButton7);
       evenOdd(jToggleButton7);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("9");
       valueCheck("9",jToggleButton9);
       evenOdd(jToggleButton9);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
       processValue("+");
       for(JToggleButton b: buttons)
           b.setSelected(false);
        if(values.contains("+"))
            jToggleButton12.setSelected(true);
    }                                               

    private void jToggleButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
       processValue("-");
       for(JToggleButton b: buttons)
           b.setSelected(false);
        if(values.contains("-"))
            jToggleButton11.setSelected(true);
    }                                               

    private void jToggleButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
       processValue("*");
       for(JToggleButton b: buttons)
           b.setSelected(false);
        if(values.contains("*"))
            jToggleButton10.setSelected(true);
    }                                               

    private void jToggleButton13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
       processValue("/");
       for(JToggleButton b: buttons)
           b.setSelected(false);
        if(values.contains("/"))
            jToggleButton13.setSelected(true);
    }                                               

    private void jToggleButton14ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        long total=-1;
        int firstNumber=-1;
        int secondNumber=-1;
        String process=null;
        for (String secilenler : values) {
            if(secilenler.equals("+"))
                process="+";  
            else if(secilenler.equals("-"))
                process="-";
            else if(secilenler.equals("*"))
                process="*"; 
            else if(secilenler.equals("/"))
                process="/";    
            else
            {
                if(firstNumber==-1)
                   firstNumber= Integer.parseInt(secilenler);
                else
                    secondNumber= Integer.parseInt(secilenler);
            }
        }
           if(process.equals("+"))
                total=firstNumber+secondNumber;
            else if(process.equals("-"))
                total=firstNumber-secondNumber;
            else if(process.equals("*"))
                total=firstNumber*secondNumber;
            else 
                total=firstNumber/secondNumber;
           jTextField1.setText(""+total);
    }                                               

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CalculatorView_1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton10;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton11;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton12;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton13;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton14;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton2;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton3;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton4;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton5;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton6;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton7;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton8;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton9;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    {
        evenNumbers.add("2");
        evenNumbers.add("4");
        evenNumbers.add("6");
        evenNumbers.add("8");
    }
    private List<String> oddNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    {
        oddNumbers.add("1");
        oddNumbers.add("3");
        oddNumbers.add("5");
        oddNumbers.add("7");
        oddNumbers.add("9");
    }
    public void processValue(String strValue)
    {
        if(values.contains(strValue))
            values.remove(strValue);
        else
            values.add(strValue);
    }

    public void valueCheck(String value,JToggleButton button) {
        if(values.size()>2) 
        {
            processValue(value);
            button.setSelected(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You cant click 3 buttons at the same time..");
        }
    }
    public boolean evenOdd(JToggleButton buton)
    {
        if(values.size()==2)
        {
        System.out.println((String)values.get(0));
        System.out.println((String)values.get(1));

        String number1 = new String(values.get(0));
        String number2 = new String(values.get(1));

        if(evenNumbers.contains(number1))
        {
            if(evenNumbers.contains(number2))
            {
                processValue(number1);
                processValue(number2);
            }
            else if(oddNumbers.contains(number2))
            {
                buton.setSelected(false);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You cant click an even and an odd number at the same time..");

            }
        }
        else if(oddNumbers.contains(number1))
        {
            if(oddNumbers.contains(number2))
            {
                processValue(number1);
                processValue(number2);
            }
            else if(evenNumbers.contains(number2))
            {
                buton.setSelected(false);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You cant click an even and an odd number at the same time..");
            }
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have multithreading, so when `evenOdd` is running, nothing else is. So what do you mean?

Comment: I mean;valueCheck method's work is not clicking 3 buttons at the same time.evenOdd method's work is not clicking an even and an odd number at the same time.For example I've clicked 2 and then 3.There will be a warn that "You cant click an even and an odd together" then i want to click an even number such as 4,6,8.Now there will be a warn that "You cant click 3 buttons together".Then i cant click an even number.So these methods cant run correctly at the same time.

Comment: can you share your particlar aim you need to achive through this?

Comment: I want to stop calling valueCheck when evenOdd is running thats my aim

Comment: Well, congratulations, you reached your aim! You never call `valueCheck` when `evenOdd` is running.

Comment: you can use wait() and noyify() method to put the evenOdd in wait when calueCheck() is runnning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not related to multithreading. [Multithreading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) involves multiple [threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), thus the word itself. In your situation, what you want to do can be achieved with simple if-else statement and proper return value from the involved methods.

I see that your method `evenOdd()` already returns `boolean`. You can take advantage from that. After displaying your error message in `evenOdd()`, make it to return false. Then, when the toggle button is pressed, test if `evenOdd()` returns true then call `valueCheck()`, else, if it returns false (error message was displayed), do not call it.

```
if(evenOdd(jToggleButton1))
   valueCheck("1", jToggleButton1);
```

Also, your current method names are confusing. Try playing with the way you name your methods. Methods should be named in such way that when you see it, you already know what it does.

Comment: I made the evenOdd() method return false but I couldnt understand the other part of your answer.Where should I use that if-else statement?And how does it work?

Comment: Let me clarify, what you want is to not call `valueCheck()` when `evenOdd()` shows you an error message. No?

Comment: Inside the method `evenOdd()`, in the code that displays `JOptionPane`, after that, return `false`. See the code in my answer? It is translated to If `evenOdd()` returns `true`, then execute `valueCheck()`. Like we've said **`evenOdd` will return `false` when error message is displayed**, so in case `evenOdd` show you an error message, `valueCheck` will not be executed. Goal achieved.

Comment: I understood thanks for your help it's compiled and solution worked